# sending emails with empty body

Tags: php, phpmailer

Is there any reason why phpmailer will send emails with empty body on a remote server but works fine on a local server?

The code is the same

```
    $res = $db->run("SELECT * FROM email WHERE code = 'welcome'");
    $m = $res[0];

    $body = nl2br($m['content']);
    $body = str_replace("[EMAIL]", $ld['email'], $body);
    $body = str_replace("[PASSWORD]", $ld['password'], $body);

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->AddReplyTo($m['from_address'], $m['from_name']);
    $mail->AddAddress($ld['email'], "");
    $mail->SetFrom($m['from_address'], $m['from_name']);
    $mail->Subject = $m['subject'];
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    if ($mail->Send() === false)
    {
        p($mail->ErrorInfo);
    }
    unset($mail);
```

Comment: The code is the same. The DB contents too? We assume that $res contains exactly the same in both places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody finds this and has no clue just like me, an update to phpmailer 5.2.6 will fix this.